# Laravel 4 Authenticating Credentials not working correctly

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4, credentials

I've followed an example for create login with laravel 4 but I have problem with it, all the time also if the credentials are correct it said "Credentials invalid." Here my code

User.php

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface{
    protected $table = "user";
    protected $hidden = ["password"];

    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getRememberToken()
    {
        return $this->remember_token;
    }

    public function setRememberToken($value)
    {
        $this->remember_token = $value;
    }

    public function getRememberTokenName()
    {
        return "remember_token";
    }

    public function getReminderEmail()

    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

UserController.php

```
<?php

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->isPostRequest()) {
            $validator = $this->getLoginValidator();

            if ($validator->passes()) {

                $credentials = $this->getLoginCredentials();

                if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
                    print_r($credentials);
                    return Redirect::route("user/profile");
                }

                return Redirect::back()->withErrors([
                    "password" => ["Credentials invalid."]
                    ]);
            } else {
                return Redirect::back()
                ->withInput()
                ->withErrors($validator);
            }
        }

        return View::make("user/login");
    }

    protected function isPostRequest()
    {
        return Input::server("REQUEST_METHOD") == "POST";
    }

    protected function getLoginValidator()
    {
        return Validator::make(Input::all(), [
            "username" => "required",
            "password" => "required"
            ]);
    }

    protected function getLoginCredentials()
    {
        return [
        "username" => Input::get("username"),
        "password" => Input::get("password")
        ];
    }
}
```

login.blade.php

```
@extends("layout")
@section("content")
{{ Form::open() }}
{{ $errors->first("password") }}<br />
{{ Form::label("username", "Username") }}
{{ Form::text("username", Input::old("username")) }}
{{ Form::label("password", "Password") }}
{{ Form::password("password") }}
{{ Form::submit("login") }}
{{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but FYI `getLoginCredentials` could be `Input::only('username', 'password')`, and `isPostRequest` could be `Request::isMethod('post')`

Comment: Are the credentials you received from your form what you expect them to be? Try adding `dd(Input::only('username', 'password'));` inside the `if ($this->isPostRequest())` block and see if you the credentials are being passed correctly to your controller.

Comment: Yes I have tried and is correct : array(2) { ["username"]=> string(4) "test" ["password"]=> string(4) "test" }

Comment: How did you create the user record in the first place? I'm thinking that perhaps the hash value that is being generated is not equaling the hash value that is in the database. Perhaps you have changed the values of 'key' or 'cipher' in config/app.php since the point in time at which you created the record?

Comment: Yes I found that, thank you very much!